# Is there a way to force text to NOT wrap to the next line?

Tags: beamer, wrap

Is there a way to force text (in a `beamer` slide) not to overflow to the next line, regardless of whether it fits into the page or not?

Comment: you might use `\rlap{...}` to allow a line to exceed the usual line width.  of course, this must be done on a case-by-case basis, and may also require the use of a forced line break if the "overflow text" is followed by more text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you box the contents inside `\mbox` (say), it doesn't know the length and therefore doesn't break/wrap:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is a the frame title}
  Here is some text that will flow from this line into the following line.

  \mbox{Here is some text that will NOT flow from this line into the following line.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is actually not working for some reason in my beamer slide. Is there any reason that it could be the case? (the text still wraps even when surrounded by \mbox)

Comment: it must be related to something specific in my beamer .tex file, because your example does work.

Comment: @kloop: Well then, [edit your post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/82799/edit) with an example that shows it doesn't work. Note that `\mbox` will only box the argument. If used in conjunction with other elements on the same line, it may break before/after `\mbox`, but not inside of it.